# Kurento Server remote stream not returning data

Tags: kurento

I am working my way through the kurento-hello-world java tutorial, but I am having issues with receiving the remote stream. There are no errors, but the remote stream just stays in the spinner and never connects.

I am running my actual kms on a remote machine which my local kurento-hello-world is connecting to. The machine has ports 80, 443, 22, and 8888 for tcp and just 8888 for udp open. I am guessing that there is another port I will need to open in order for the remote stream to start returning data, but I am not sure which.

These are the last lines returning in the console before nothing happens:

```
i Received message: {"id":"startResponse","sdpAnswer":"v=0\r\no=- 3652452626 3652452626 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=Kurento Media Server\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\nt=0 0\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS UmE2pKdEGXnmq7rvsW64iUGKe2JmNy5MNO0y\r\na=group:BUNDLE\r\nm=audio 0 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 126\r\na=mid:audio\r\nm=video 0 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100 116 117 96\r\na=mid:video\r\n"}
> SDP answer received from server. Processing ...
> SDP answer received, setting remote description
> Remote URL: ''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure a STUN server if your KMS is behind a NAT. Please read the [documentation](https://www.kurento.org/docs/current/installation_guide.html#stun-and-turn-servers) for information about how to configure those.

I suggest you also read something about WebRTC and STUN/TURN in general, as that will save you from a lot of trouble. [This](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) would be a good start.

Comment: No worries! Anytime ;-)